# Webscraping video links with Selenium

Tags: python, flash, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using python + Selenium for this:
been trying to write a **scraper** to test a website that goes into the site, navigate to video urls, and faces a problem:
When in the video page, a flash component .swf loads a .mp4 within it. I can easily get the link for the mp4 once the swf is loaded, since it modifies the html and adds a "flashvars" element, from which I get my url.
It works nice when navigating with Chrome and Firefox, but when I try PhantomJS, I can't find the element, because Phantom does not support flash plugin, so the flashvars element is not created.

Is there a workaround for this? I really want to make the process headles.

Comment: maybe you can use an older version of PhantomJS that supports flash

Comment: Can you please post the code and the error that you get?